# Get curl http code

Tags: bash, shell, http, curl

I have the following cURL request. I want to get the http_code, but I want in a different variable, because otherwise it messes with parsing the JSON response from the GET call.

Is there anyway to do this?

```
curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "URL"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use command substitution to store status code in a variable:

```
status=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output tmp.out GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "URL")
data=$(<tmp.out)

# check status now
declare -p status

# check data
declare -p data
```

Comment: I also need the actual output though. Does this give me both the output and the status code?

Comment: This just appends the status code to the end of the JSON response.

Comment: But you have `--output /dev/null` which is suppressing all the output.

Comment: My bad! That was a typo. Lemme edit that in the question. Any suggestions now?

Comment: @anubhava: This is what I see as output

declare -- status="000<JSON_RESPONSE>200"
declare -- data=""

Not exactly what I wanted, but I think you're close?

Comment: But you need to provide a valid URL in the end of `curl` command which is not part shown in your question

Comment: I used a valid URL. It's an API endpoint, but I can't share it publicly. It works though.

Answer (score 0):

curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" "server:5050/a/c/getName{"param0":"Arvind "}"

Comment: This is just functioning as a regular curl request.

Answer (score 0):

curl -w 'RESP_CODE:%{response_code}' -s -X POST --data '{"asda":"asd"}' http://example.com --header "Content-Type:application/json"|grep -o  'RESP_CODE:[1-4][0-9][0-9]'

Comment: I need both the response code AND the actual JSON response

Answer (score 0):

response=$(curl -sb -H "Accept: application/json" "http://host:8080/some/resource")   For response just try $response

Answer (score 0):

Try this following may be this could help you to find the solution https://gist.github.com/sgykfjsm/1dd9a8eee1f70a7068c9